# Webview + proguard crashing on a certain device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, proguard

Hey Stack Overflow Community,
I recently received a new crash from crashlytics which is only happening on a device Samsung Galaxy J7(2016) with android version 8.1.0. However, i tested the same steps ( as logged by firebase) and tried by that user on the same device (i have the same device at workplace with the same android os version). No crashes happened to me, so if you people can advice, it would be appreciated.
Crash logs:

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #105: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView


Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #105: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView


Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:995)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:15)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:645)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:93)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:42)
   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:173)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:38)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:113)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:88)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:21)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7025)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)


Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo; in class Landroid/webkit/WebViewFactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.webkit.WebViewFactory' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes2.dex)
   at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.f(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:4)
   at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.<init>(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:12)
   at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForOMR1.<init>(WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForOMR1.java:1)
   at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForOMR1.create(WebViewChromiumFactoryProviderForOMR1.java:1)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:208)
   at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2530)
   at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2525)
   at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2590)
   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4868)
   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5054)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:597)
   at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:643)
   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:588)
   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:571)
   at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:558)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:720)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:788)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:995)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:15)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:645)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:93)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:42)
   at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:173)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:38)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:113)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:88)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:21)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7025)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Can you show your xml file ?

Answer (score -1):

Please ask the user to install the latest version of WebView from Google Play, and see if that will solve the problem.

Comment: Hey my friend, i don't know who downvoted you, but in most scenarios your app is live and you don't know your users personally to ask them or demand something from them

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made the wrong assumption that you could contact the user.